# Set visibility of Layer inside a LayerDrawable

Tags: android, visibility, drawable

I've defined a LayerDrawable with a few items by code but I dont know how to set the visibility of each layer inside the LayerDrawable that "imagen" have. This is my code:

public class layerExample extends Activity {

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ImageView imagen = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);                

    Resources r = getResources();
    Drawable[] capas = new Drawable[3];

    capas[0] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
    capas[1] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon2);
    capas[2] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon3);           

    LayerDrawable capasDrawable = new LayerDrawable(capas);
    imagen.setImageDrawable(capasDrawable);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do a call to

```
<drawable object>.setAlpha(int i)
```

i : 0 means fully transparent and 255 means fully opaque

Comment: Only works sporadically on certain API / device combos.